# Is it necessary to add a constant to a logit model run on categorical variables only?

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

And am running a logit model on fluid as dependent variable, and excluding `vp` and `perip`:

```py
model = smf.logit('''fluid ~ C(examq3_n, Treatment(reference = 2.0)) + C(pmhq3_n) + C(fluidq3_n) + C(mapq3_n, Treatment(reference = 3.0)) + 
                  C(examq6_n, Treatment(reference = 2.0)) + C(pmhq6_n) + C(fluidq6_n) + C(mapq6_n, Treatment(reference = 3.0)) +
                  + C(case, Treatment(reference = 2))''',
                      data = case1_2_vars).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

I get the following results:
[image]

I am wondering if I need to add a constant to the data and if so, how? I've tried adding a column to the dataframe called `const` which equals `1`, but when I then add `const` to the logit equation I get `LinAlgError: Singular Matrix,` and I don't know how to add it using `smf.add_constant()` because I have had to specify the categorical variables and their respective reference numbers in the equation, rather than defining `x` and `y` separately and simply inputting those into the `smf.logit()` call.

My questions are: a) do I need to add a constant, and b) how? There are some links online that seem to imply it might not be necessary for a categorical variable-based logit model, but I would rather do it if it's best practice.

I'm also wondering, does statsmodels automatically include a constant? Because `Intercept` is listed in the results.

Comment: `LinAlgError: Singular Matrix` This error implies that the column you added is a multiple of some other column in the matrix, i.e. that there is already a constant term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use formulas, then the formula handling by patsy adds automatically a constant/intercept.
(when using e.g. `smf.logit` or `sm.Logit.from_formula`)

If you create a model without formula using numpy arrays or pandas DataFrame, then the `exog` is not changed by statsmodels, i.e. users needs to add a constant themselves. The helper function is `sm.add_constant` which adds a column of ones to the array or DataFrame.
(when using e.g. `sm.Logit(y, x)`)